# Play scala openid redirect always to recover

Tags: scala, openid, playframework-2.2, redirect, recover

Im trying to connect to my openid provider through play scala.

I use openID.redirectURL and than send the answer to a map function but somehow it never .sends any request to my provider. It always goes into the recover part.

My code 
OpenID.redirectURL(myProviderUrl,ComeBackUrl).map( url => Redirect(url)).recover{ case t:Throwable =>{ Logger.info("recover") Redirect(routes.testCallBack.authError)}}

BTW, i dont have ide on my computer for scala, so if everything seems right at my code, i would be grateful if you would write the necessary imports for this code.

P.S. - if someone can pls edit this text to code block it would be great, im posting this through my phone..

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Try logging the actual error and you will probably see what is wrong:

```
OpenID.redirectURL(myProviderUrl, ComeBackUrl)
  .map( url => Redirect(url))
  .recover{ 
    case t: Throwable =>
      Logger.warn("Openid failed", t) 
      Redirect(routes.testCallBack.authError)
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the problem is : ConnectException : Genarel SSLEngine. If i understood it right its because i defined my provider certifcate self-signed and i added the CA to my computer.